# Text based emacs modeline

Tags: emacs, modeline

How do we use text-only based modeline in emacs ?

I don't want a big button across the screen at the bootom of my emacs window.
Just a text line with all the contents would be good and minimal.

Similarly when I do a split screen, I don't want a scroll bar, just a "|" character
across the entire screen is enough. Is this possible ?

Comment: use `scroll-bar-mode` to get rid of the scroll-bar

Comment: If you don't know how to change the faces in your mode-line I suggest you use the smart-mode-line package. Among other features it redefines the faces used in the mode-line. https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/smart-mode-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `mode-line-faces` <kbd>RET</kbd>

To completely get rid of the 'button' appearance, remove the 'box' attribute from `mode-line`, `mode-line-highlight`, and `mode-line-inactive`.

Comment: exactly what I wanted for the modeline.

Comment: (set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil :box nil)                          (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-inactive nil :box nil)               (set-face-attribute 'mode-line-highlight nil :box nil) works good, but when I set a new color-theme, all of it goes away.

Answer (score 3):

Doing `(set-scroll-bar-mode nil)` will remove the scrollbars (you can even use yascroll.el to use fringe-based scrollbars, less obtrusive than the widget based).

Regarding what you call "big button"... I think the modeline face you are using makes it look like a button (i.e., has a "beveled" border).  You can change the face to look like a normal text face, with or without border, and the size you want.  This is what I do.  I think some themes (like solarized) do that, so you can test one of them to have a feeling of how that would work.

Comment: yascroll.el is a neat solution, Just that the fringe jumps when scrolling instead of a smooth scroll.